# ASP.NET and WordPress

Tags: asp.net, .net, wordpress, apache, azure

I have 2 websites (www.example.co.uk and www.example.net)

- www.example.co.uk is a WordPress brochure website (front end)
- www.example.net is built in asp.net and is hosted on Microsoft's AZURE and allows people to manage their data etc. (back end)

People are getting confused when they visit www.example.co.uk and then end up at www.example.net to manage their account. Would it be possible to host them both under the same domain (still keeping them separate) so people don't get confused?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can by hosted on azure, but domain will be www.example.net/wordpresssite or wordpresssite.example.net

Comment: could i host the .net site where the wordpress website is so the domain would be www.example.co.uk/wordpresssite or wordpresssite.example.co.uk instead of .net

Comment: Yes you can by using custom domains in the app service

Comment: @sc2015 Yes, you can. You just purchase the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the detailed steps for you to configure your custom domain, you could refer to it.

I assume that your domain is `example.co.uk` and the domain of your back-end hosted on Azure is `wordpresssite.azurewebsites.net` by default.

Firstly, you need to log in to your domain registrar and add a CNAME record as follows:

```
|---------FQDN EXAMPLE--------|--CNAME HOST---|------------CNAME VALUE----------|
| wordpresssite.example.co.uk | wordpresssite | wordpresssite.azurewebsites.net |
```

Then, you need to log in to the Azure Portal, select your web app, click Custom domains > Add hostname to enable the custom domain name for your app. After you finish the configuration steps,it would take some period for the changes to propagate, depending on your DNS provider. And you could verify the DNS status by using [digwebinterface.com](http://digwebinterface.com/). For more details, you could follow [web-sites-custom-domain-name](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/).